# How to get previous element text from keyword with bs4

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML. Im trying to figure out how to retrieve the span tag text `Verizon`. This value changes depending on my use case, However the `<a>` text doesn't. The way I'm trying to approach this is to search for the text `Company` from the `<a>` tag as a reference point and use something like `.find_previous.sibling('a')` to get the text from the field directly above it. However, I think this is the wrong way to go about it.

```
<table class="data_table  server_information">
   <tr class="data_table_header">
      <td colspan="100%">
         Table Information
      </td>
      </span>
      <span data-clicktoclipboard="Verizon" style="cursor: copy; ">
      Verizon
      </span>
      <a class="button" href="https://randomsite.com" target="_blank">
      Company
      </a>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The desired output is to just print:

```
Verizon
```

I guess i would need a way of accessing the above field regardless of the type of tag.

I have this idea so far:

```
src = open("example.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "html.parser")
trs = soup.findAll("tr")
for i in range(len(trs)):
    if 'class' in trs[i].td.attrs and trs[i].td.text == 'Company':
           soup.find_previous_sibling().text)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use CSS selector with `+` ([doc](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)):

```py
print(soup.select_one(":has(+ :-soup-contains(Company))").text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
Verizon
```

---

Complete code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<table class="data_table  server_information">
   <tr class="data_table_header">
      <td colspan="100%">
         Table Information
      </td>
      </span>
      <span data-clicktoclipboard="Verizon" style="cursor: copy; ">
      Verizon
      </span>
      <a class="button" href="https://randomsite.com" target="_blank">
      Company
      </a>
   </tr>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one(":has(+ :-soup-contains(Company))").text.strip())
```

---

Or using bs4 API:

```py
print(
    soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "a" and tag.text.strip() == "Company")
    .find_previous()
    .get_text(strip=True)
)
```